# Component like ubuntu unity's overlay scrollbar

Tags: delphi, components, scrollbar

Is there a component like ubuntu unity's overlay scrollbar for Delphi?

[image]

See also this video: http://vimeo.com/20523493

I use mostly Delphi 2007 but I don't really mind about the version.

Comment: You cannot be serious! That is the most diabolical piece of UI design I've seen in recent times and it's been widely slated. Almost all discussion of it involves how to remove it. If you do add something to your product, make sure you have a plan B in place for when you get similar wails of distaste.

Comment: @David, I appreciate your candor. I like the space efficiency of it. I was thinking of implementing it in Delphi using transparent overlays, a bit like google earth's controls, so the scrollbar looks like normal, transparent when not in use, so it doesn't obscure the text below it, it is not so small that you cannot `hit` it with your mouse (fitt's law)

Comment: I like nice big scroll bars that I can always see and are easy to get hold of!

Comment: I'm all for that too, but I want them to be near transparent when not in use so I have more screen space to work with.

Comment: You'll be asking about skinning next!

Comment: @david, you are a jester :-), but seriously the amount of space waste that is the scrollbar has bugged me for years. This is esp vexing in forms with multiple `TScrollingWinControl` desendents, but since we are talking about skinning, I'd like: my menu where the titlebar is (another huge waste of space) and if I can have a pony too that would be really cool, also I believe the scrollbar should do double duty as splitter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The past few months I've worked with Ubuntu quite a bit, and one of the first things I did was to uninstall the scrollbar changes with `sudo apt-get remove scrollbar*` After that Ubuntu Unity became almost usable :-).

Comment: Scrollbars that are always visible show you valuable state (where am I in respect to the available content) and hiding them is stupid.  Mac OS X Lion does this too, and I hate it there too.

Comment: @WarrenP, I use the magic mouse on the Mac, since that day the lack of visible scrollbars is more bearable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I have seen is the scrolling behaviour in the [TMS Smooth Listbox](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothlistbox.asp).

It doesn't go "outboard" like your sample image, but instead it uses zero screen real-estate (hiding the scroll bar) until you mouse over the area, then you have to mouse down and "flick" the contents up or down, like you were using an iPad or iPod-touch.

The TMS controls come with full source code, and I believe you could probably modify them to paint the way you show above, if you know enough about GDI+.

A second alternative is to implement your own separate control and scrollview-container.  Note that it's deceptively difficult to get something like this right, and that users will mostly prefer the standard windows way of working, and will quickly ask you for a configuration option to turn your innovations off, so be sure to code in an off-switch for them.

incidentally, this is so new-school, it's old school.  The image/style for a thin line, and a big thumb, that ubuntu came up with is familiar to me, because it's similar to OpenLook, with the thumb moved a bit left or right, but less usable, because of the narrowness:

[image]

I particularly like this image which calls it an "elevator" which ascends and descends on a "cable":

[image]